# have send tf data from multiple robot in rviz

Tags: navigation, rviz, ros-kinetic, tf-broadcaster, joint-states

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS Kinetic:

I am using 2 robot and I am not sure how to display in in rviz with amcl. What I have is each robot has its own tf. I would do

```
<remap from="tf" to="tf1"/>
```

is that wrong? I think it is wrong because rviz can only take in one tf. I did some reading and it said instead to do.

```
<node name="robot_state_publisher" pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="state_publisher" >
<param name="tf_prefix" value="robot_0"/>
</node>
```

and

```
<node name="robot_state_publisher" pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="state_publisher" >
<param name="tf_prefix" value="robot_1"/>
</node>
```

Is one of these method right? Or is there another solution. Any help is appreciated! Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/329951/have-send-tf-data-from-multiple-robot-in-rviz/) by [Usui](https://answers.ros.org/users/36306/usui/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2019-08-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Having multiple robots on the same roscore is a real tricky challenge.  I'd recommend looking into how to solve that problem before you look into solving the TF problem.  Additionally, AMCL will only localize one robot - so you won't be able to use the same instance of that program with more than one entity you're trying to localize.

See this post for a good amount of information:
https://answers.ros.org/question/41433/multiple-robots-simulation-and-navigation/?answer=41434?answer=41434#post-id-41434

Hope this helps!

---

Originally posted by [luc](https://answers.ros.org/users/18958/luc/) with karma: 350 on 2019-08-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Usui](https://answers.ros.org/users/36306/usui/) on 2019-08-06**:
That post is uses 2 robot with amcl also. I can get 2 robot using multi machine. Do you think tf_prefix in the robot_state_publisher be able to get 2 robot in an rviz? I just need to transform it to the same global frame.

**Comment by [luc](https://answers.ros.org/users/18958/luc/) on 2019-08-08**:
They must have two separate AMCL processes running to localize the two robots.  You may be able to use a container approach to run two roscores on one machine.  Because of the way tf operates, I dont think the prefix alone will help reconcile having two robots on one roscore.  Look at the API of the tf2 buffer - it does not look as if there is a way to specify the prefix here: http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/tf2_ros/html/c++/classtf2__ros_1_1Buffer.html

**Comment by [Usui](https://answers.ros.org/users/36306/usui/) on 2019-08-08**:
@luc Okay so I started on it and I have a problem. Here's the question: https://answers.ros.org/question/330234/robot-model-not-showing-up-when-using-tf_prefix/

**Comment by [luc](https://answers.ros.org/users/18958/luc/) on 2019-08-16**:
@Usui I'll check out that question.  If this answer helped you, please mark it as correct!